# Calculating a boolean variable rowwise across a subset of columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I know there are a lot of questions and answers about how to do this sort of thing, but the problem is I know how to calculate new columns from a subset of columns, I just don't know how to do the particular operation I need

Toy data

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c(NA, 1, NA),
                v2 = c(1, 2, NA),
                v3 = c(NA, 1, NA),
                v4 = c(1, 2, 3))
d

# output
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1 NA  1 NA  1
2  1  2  1  2
3 NA NA NA  3
```

Now say I want to create a new variable that gives me the sum across columns V1 to V3. Easy enough with the new dplyr functions `rowwise()` and `across()`

```
d %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(sum = sum(c_across(v1:v3)))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
# Rowwise: 
     v1    v2    v3    v4   sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     1    NA     1    NA
2     1     2     1     2     4
3    NA    NA    NA     3    NA
```

So the summing function works. But I want to create a boolean variable that tells me whether rows `v1` to `v3` are made up entirely of NAs. I thought this would work

```
d %>%
  rowwise()
    mutate(anyEntries = all(is.na(c_across(v1:v3))))
```

but it throws the following error

```
Error in `c_across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

I am confused because the function works on a simple vector

```
all(is.na(c(NA, NA, NA)))
# [1] TRUE

all(is.na(c(NA, 1, NA)))
# [1] FALSE
```

Am I putting `c_across` in the wrong place or something?

I tested whe

Comment: you are just missing the `%>%` after `rowwise()`.  Make that a complete pipe, and your code should work just fine.

Comment: A way without `rowwise` would be e.g. `d %>% mutate(allEntries = rowSums(across(v1:v3, is.na)) == 3)`

Comment: Dammit! Thank you @langtan. Coding errors are embarrassing but at least it wasn't a fault in my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a `baseR` solution an option for you? If so I suggest using `apply` to evaluate `all(is.na(x))` to each row separately

```
v1v3 <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
d$Rsums <- rowSums(d[v1v3]) # na.rm = TRUE ?
d$allNA <- apply(d[v1v3], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

gives

```
> d
  v1 v2 v3 v4 Rsums allNA
1 NA  1 NA  1    NA FALSE
2  1  2  1  2     4 FALSE
3 NA NA NA  3    NA  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Pax. Thanks for the solution. I was looking for a tidyverse solution but I appreciate your efforts and since you're the only one with a a formal answer I'll give you the tick. l always forget apply can do rowwise operations. thanks for the reminder